# Javascript variable value back to default value after i change it

Tags: javascript, php

I declared a javascript variable at the top of the page like this:

```
<script>
    var soal = "";
</script>
```

I try to set that variable value with a value that i get from my json file. After i set the value, i try to display the value in the alert box and it works just fine. Here is the code:

```
echo "<script>
         var questionList = [];
         var question;
                                    
         fetch('json/word-list.json').then(function(response) {
             return response.json();
         }).then(function(data) {
             for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                 if(data[i].pjgkata >= 5 && data[i].pjgkata <= 6) {
                     questionList.push(data[i]);
                 }
             }
             question = questionList[Math.floor(Math.random() * questionList.length)];
             soal = question.kata;
             alert(soal);
         }).catch(function(err) {
             alert(err);
         })
      </script>";
```

After that, i try to pass the javascript variable value via link and the variable value is back to empty. Here is the code:

```
if($_POST["room-type"] == "public") {
   echo "<script>
             window.location.href = 'https://anagram.my.id/home.php?soal=' + soal;
         </script>";
} elseif($_POST["room-type"] == "private") {
   echo "<script>
             document.getElementById('description').textContent = 'Room berhasil dibuat. Kode room: ".$_SESSION['kode']."';
             document.getElementById('btn-notif').style.display = 'block';
             document.getElementById('btn-notif-logout').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('notif-modal').style.display = 'block';
         </script>";
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code that makes the javascript variable "soal" value back to empty?